# FQL: Know email, first name and last name. What is the FQL code to get the User ID on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-fql

I only know the email, first name and last name of a person. Is it possible to get the User ID through FQL? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The columns which u are having from the user table in facebook are not indexable. For fetching using the where clause u must have a indexable column. If u will try with these columns u will get the following error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ",
      "type": "NoIndexFunctionException",
      "code": 604
   }
}
```

So for getting User ID you need to have any of the indexable columns.